# Windows IoT - Zebra Bluetooth Printer

Tags: printing, bluetooth, raspberry-pi2, zebra-printers, windows-10-iot-core

I have two Zebra Bluetooth Printers, a MZ220 and iMZ220. The "only" thing I would do, is to print text with a Windows IoT System on a Raspberry Pi 2. Nothing more ;)

Example:
Line1 `"    Hello World"`
Line2 `"---------------"`
Line3 `"Date:01.01.2016"`
Line4 `"Time:     18:00"`

The USB Bluetooth Adapter BTA-403 from ORICO, I guess works well. With the Explorer I can connect to the Printer. But, what next? How do I connect to the Printer? How do I say to the Printer print `"Hello World!"`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These printers are using Bluetooth like a serial port aka SSP profile.

First, you'll have to edit your app manifest and add a new device capability

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
        <Device Id="any">
            <Function Type="name:serialPort"/>
        </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

You can get the paired printers like this

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));
```

Once you identified the right printer, you can open the connection

```
var service = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(DeviceInfo.Id);
var socket = new StreamSocket();
await socket.ConnectAsync(service.ConnectionHostName, service.ConnectionServiceName);
```

You should be able to send then information like this

```
private async void PrintAsync(string line)
{
    var writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
    var command = "^XA^LH30,30^F020,10^AD^FD + line + "^FS^XZ";
    writer.WriteString(command);
    await writer.StoreAsync();
}
```

Comment: Dear danvy, I love you... Yesterday, I received your answer. But it was late at night and I was just dreaming. But today I woked up and tested your code, it works! Nothing more too say. I thank you danvy!

Comment: 3 years later, I have the same sentiment. Thanks danvy and MeerArtefakt.