# Windows IoT - USB Printer Zebra - how to install

Tags: printing, raspberry-pi2, zebra-printers, windows-10-iot-core

I saw this question: [Windows IoT - USB Printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056276/windows-iot-usb-printer)

It is nearly similar.
The problem is; I don't know how to install the driver for this printer GX420d on windows iot - I do know how to build the cab (with inf2cab) but the printer is always shown as:
Properties:

ID : USB\VID_0A5F&PID_0084\30J163301131

Description : ZTC GX420d

StatusCode : 25191424

ProblemCode : 28

Does anyone has an idea where I can get the right ARM-Driver?

Kind Regards

Comment: Have you tried this: ["For ARM, please contact the supplier of the peripheral to get the sys/inf files."](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/peripheraldrivers) ?

Comment: Yes, no answer from them