# Sending raw print commands to Zebra from Windows 10 IoT on RPi3

Tags: windows, printing, raspberry-pi, usb, iot

I am trying to setup a simple app where my Raspberry Pi 3 can send a raw print command to a Zebra printer over USB.

I have a working WPF c# app that will run on my desktop using the `RawPrinterHelper` class similar to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091, but the winspool.Drv won't work on the Pi3 because of the ARM processor (from what I understand).

Seeing as Windows 10 IoT requires UWP apps, I am trying to re-write the app in UWP. I have the app working, but can't figure out how to send the raw commands over USB without the `winspool.Drv` from the `RawPrinterHelper` class.

I have also tried sending over Bluetooth as described here: [Windows IoT - Zebra Bluetooth Printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510095/windows-iot-zebra-bluetooth-printer)
 but can't seem to open a connection to my paired device as `var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));` doesn't return any devices. Here is my code:

```
    private async void PrintAsync()
    {
        textBox.Text = "Searching for devices";

        var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));

        if(devices.Count() == 0)
        {
            textBox.Text = "No devices found";
            return;
        }

        textBox.Text = "Number of paired devices found: " + devices.Count();

        var service = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync("DepotPrinter");
        var socket = new StreamSocket();
        await socket.ConnectAsync(service.ConnectionHostName, service.ConnectionServiceName);

        var writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
        var command = "^XA"
        + "^FO20,175^A0N,40,25^FD" + "Yo." + "^FS"
        + "^FO20,250^A0N,40,25^FD" + "IT WORKED!" + "^FS"
        + "^XZ";
        writer.WriteString(command);
        await writer.StoreAsync();
    }
```

I would be willing to run my app on mono and Raspbian if it can work.

Any help or direction would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I am using the on-board bluetooth of the RP3 and not a dongle.

Comment: Have you used on-chip Bluetooth or external dongle?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Shift No yet. I was told on the msdn forum that it might not be possible because of the lack of drivers for Windows IoT. I have ordered a serial card for the printer and will try sending the commands via the RPi3's serial port. I will update this post if I can get it to work.